# CakePHP only get results that have a related model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my CakePHP 2 project, I have Projects that have many Articles, an Article can belong to many projects (a many-to-many relation).

Now I would like to find all Projects that have an Article.
My current code for getting the Projects is as follows

```
$projects = $this->Project->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Project.slug', 'Project.name')
));
```

I tried adding contain to the query, without results

```
$projects = $this->Project->find('list', array(
    'contain' => array('PressArticles' => array()),
    'fields' => array('Project.slug', 'Project.name')
));
```

**How can I modify this so I receive all projects that have an article?**

Answer (score 0):

Containing won't help, non-1:1 relations will be retrieved in a separate query, so that won't have any effect on your main query.

You could for example manually create `INNER` joins with the association's join and target table, that would automatically filter out all projects that have no associated articles, something along the lines of this (I've more or less guessed the names, it's just a quick and dirty example):

```
$projects = $this->Project->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Project.slug', 'Project.name'),
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'table' => 'press_articles_projects',
            'alias' => 'PressArticleProject',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'PressArticleProject.project_id = Project.id',
            ),
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'press_articles',
            'alias' => 'PressArticle',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'PressArticle.id = PressArticleProject.press_article_id',
            ),
        )
    ),
    'group' => 'Project.id'
));
```

Or if you are using a counter cache, then filtering by the counter would be an option too:

```
$projects = $this->Project->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('Project.slug', 'Project.name'),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Project.press_article_count >' => 0
    )
));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > Joining tables](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables)**
- **[Cookbook > Models > Associations: Linking Models Together > counterCache - Cache your count()](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#countercache-cache-your-count)**

Answer (score 0):

In your `Project` model, you can do

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'PressArticle' => array(
            'className' => 'PressArticle',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id'
        )
    );
```

For more info, check [here](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany)